# Grouping columns by type

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a master table like this

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| id |  user_id  |   date     |  vehicle_type  |  
+----------------------------------------------+
| 1  |  1        | 2017-06-01 |       1        |
| 2  |  1        | 2017-06-01 |       2        |
| 3  |  1        | 2017-06-01 |       1        |
| 4  |  1        | 2017-06-02 |       2        |
| 5  |  1        | 2017-06-02 |       1        |
| 6  |  2        | 2017-06-01 |       2        |
| 7  |  2        | 2017-06-01 |       1        |
| 8  |  2        | 2017-06-01 |       2        |
| 9  |  2        | 2017-06-02 |       1        |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

I want to group by `user_id` and `date`, and sum the vehicle_type depend on its value, and create as view.
here the output i want

```
+------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
| id |  user_id  |   date     |  vehicle_type_1  |   vehicle_type_2  |
+------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
| 1  |  1        | 2017-06-01 |       2          |          2        |
| 4  |  1        | 2017-06-02 |       1          |          1        |
| 6  |  2        | 2017-06-01 |       1          |          2        |
| 9  |  2        | 2017-06-02 |       1          |          0        |
+------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

the question is the best sql(query) to get output like i want.
Thanks,

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: i tried to create 2(vehicle_type_1 and vehicle_type_2) view then i join

Comment: Are there only ever 2 types of vehicles can there be a third;( forth etc?)  Do you need dynamic SQL pivot? or just a pivot? or will a simple case statement work?

Comment: i have static vehicle_type, only 1, 2, 3, and 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use case statement to get required output. Try below one

```
 select max(id) id,user_id,date,sum(case when vehicle_type=1 then 1 else 0 end) vehicle_type_1,sum(case when vehicle_type=2 then 1 else 0 end) vehicle_type_2  from urtable 
    group by user_id,date
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT user_id 
  ,date
  ,SUM(IIF(vehicle_type = 1,1,0)) as vehicle_type_1
  ,SUM(IIF(vehicle_type = 2,1,0)) as vehicle_type_2 
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY user_id, date
```

i don't get it why you need the id in your output. if really needed, just add MIN(id) or MAX(id) in the select clause

Comment: i have tried but i  get function  IFF does not exist

Comment: so just juse 
case when vehicle_type=1 then 1 else 0 end
instead of IIF(vehicle_type = 2,1,0)

Comment: @Adzimzf: replace **`IIF`** with **`IF`**.

Answer (score 0):

According to description mentioned in above question as a solution to it please try executing following SQL select query

```
    SELECT user_id, 
       date, 
       Count(id)        AS vehicle_type_1, 
       (SELECT Count(id) 
        FROM   mytbl 
        WHERE  vehicle_type = 2 
               AND user_id = tbl.user_id 
               AND date = tbl.date 
        GROUP  BY user_id, 
                  date) AS vehicle_type_2 
FROM   mytbl AS tbl 
WHERE  vehicle_type = 1 
GROUP  BY user_id, 
          date
```